# Making N sequential api calls using RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a list of files that I'd like to upload to the backend from an Android device. Due to memory constraints, I'd like to make the second API call only after the first finished, the third after the second finished, and so on.

I wrote something like

```
private Observable<Integer> uploadFiles(List<File> files) {
        return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            for (int i = 0, size = files.size(); i < size; i++) {
                UploadModel uploadModel = new UploadModel(files.get(0));
                int uploadResult = retrofitApi.uploadSynchronously(uploadModel);
                subscriber.onNext(uploadResult);
            }
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
    }
```

But I feel like this might be going against the spirit of Rx, and the saying is if you're using Observable.create, you're probably doing it wrong...
Is this a reasonable approach? Is there a better way to achieve this with Retrofit's RxJava integration?

Comment: Why not define in your API interface `uploadSynchronously` to **not** return Observable? Another way is to use toBlocking on each observable.

Comment: That is what I did - retrofitApi.uploadSynchronously is a blocking retrofit call that returns an int, not an observable. And if your question is why I didn't do a simple loop without Rx, well, it would have been difficult to handle errors and UI progress updates elegantly, plus there are some additional steps before and after this Observable in the chain.

Comment: Actually, no, I it seems for me that basic loop is preferable here over using `map`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naively, I would do that (it does not work, though, see below):

```
return Observable.from(files).concatMap(file -> retrofitApi.upload(uploadModel));
```

Now the issue is that there is no way to tell retrofit to use only one thread for those calls.

`reduce`, however, passes the result of one function call to the next, along with the next emitted value from the original observable. That would work, but the function passed to `reduce` needs to be synchronous. Not good.

Another approach would be to modify the observable recursively:

```
void getNextFile(int i) {
    return retrofit.upload(i).
        onNext(result -> getNextFile(i + 1));
}
```

roughly. But I am not sure how to clean it to make it more readable.

The cleanest I would think would be something like:

```
Observable.from(files).map(file -> retrofitApi.uploadSynchronously(new UploadModel(file)));
```

Comment: Observable.from is what I initially went with (but with the Observable retrofit call) and that way it all got called in parallel. Will this block the chain with each call and emit the result to onNext()?

Comment: The thing I can't figure out is how to trigger the next call from the previous one, other than re-creating observables every time. The last suggestion should work, because `map` is called on only one thread.

Comment: Your final solution works exactly as intended, and it looks a lot less shady than my initial one, so thanks! I just needed to push map to a new thread at the start of the chain, but then everything ran on that one.

Thanks!

Comment: as a side note, rather that `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`, for network calls, it is recommended to use `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, as it will use a dedicated thread pool for io operations.

Comment: Are you certain about that? I recall reading that .io should not be used for network, only local stuff.

Comment: the documentation is pretty clear, and I have been using schedulers.io for some time. Now there may be something specific about android, if you can remember where you read that I would be very interested

Comment: Hm, I must have mis-remembered as I can't find anything saying that. So you are indeed correct, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The natives of RxJava would emit all items in `Observable.from(...)` as if in parallel. That's the best way to think of it as parallel emission. However some cases require real consequent execution of the whole chain. I've come to the following solution, probably not the best one but working.

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Rx {
    public static void ignore(Object arg) {
    }

    public static <E, R> Observable<Void> sequential(Iterator<E> iterator, Function<E, Observable<R>> action) {
        return Observable.create(collectorSubscriber ->
                Observable.<Void>create(producerSubscriber ->
                        producerSubscriber.setProducer(ignoredCount -> {
                            if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
                                producerSubscriber.onCompleted();
                                return;
                            }

                            E model = iterator.next();
                            action.apply(model)
                                    .subscribe(
                                            Rx::ignore,
                                            producerSubscriber::onError,
                                            () -> producerSubscriber.onNext(null));
                        }))
                        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStart() {
                                request(1);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {
                                collectorSubscriber.onNext(null);
                                collectorSubscriber.onCompleted();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                collectorSubscriber.onError(e);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(Void aVoid) {
                                request(1);
                            }
                        }));
    }
}
```

Example usage would be:

```
    Iterator<? extends Model> iterator = models.iterator();

    Rx.sequential(iterator, model -> someFunctionReturnsObservable(model))
            .subscribe(...);
```

This method guarantees chained executions of

`Observable<Dummy> someFunctionReturnsObservable(Model model)`

Answer (score 0):

Currently the prefered way of creating observables is with fromAsync:

```
Observable.fromAsync(new Action1<AsyncEmitter<Object>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(final AsyncEmitter<Object> emitter)
        {
            emitter.onNext(object);
            emitter.onCompleted();

            emitter.setCancellation(new AsyncEmitter.Cancellable()
            {
                @Override
                public void cancel() throws Exception
                {
                    // on unSubscribe() callback
                }
            });
        }
    }, AsyncEmitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER);
```