# android RxJava Observable.from to post to a service

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a list of items which i need to extract some values and make an api call for each of the item. To do that, i'm using something like this_

```
Observable.from(myList)
   .flatMap{ item ->
      return serviceInteractor.uploadToServer(item)
   }
   .map { serverResponse ->
       return serverResponse.getResponseCode
   }
   .toList()
   .subscrible{ responseList ->
   // do something with all the responses
   }
```

Ok so the problem is, i don't know why all the calls are made in parallel.
Isn't it supposed to wait for the first response, map the results, proceed to the next item from the Observable.from() and at the end return the final list of responseMessages? What is happening is, everything happens at the same time. To confirm this, if i put a delay(1, TimeUnit.Seconds) before the `toList` method, everything happens at the same time, only the final onNext is delayed.

How can i accomplish this? Have a list of ids, want to upload to server one by one, waiting for each one to complete, proceed to next if success or fail

Comment: no, it is not supposed to do that.

Comment: this answer describe an operator to do what you ask: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33633753/671543

Comment: Shouldn't the first flatMap be a simple map operator since the Observable.from(list) returns an Observable<Item> already?  I'm not experienced with RxJava though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to use `ConcatMap`

Flat map uses [merge operator](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#merge) while concatMap uses [concat opertor](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#concat).

so sequence will be like this

flatMap output sequence is `merged`
concatMap output sequence is `ordered`

as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24595644/942224)

here you can take a look on this example

```
String arrData[] = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4"};
Integer arrDelay[] = {1000, 6000, 4000, 9000, 2000};

Observable.from(arrData)
            .concatMap(s -> Observable.from(arrData)
                      .delay(arrDelay[Integer.parseInt(s)],TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))

            .map(integer -> integer)
            .toList()
            .doOnCompleted(() -> Log.v("log", "doOnCompleted"))
            .subscribe(integer -> Log.v("log", "" + integer));
```

here you can check that delay will be total of `arrDelay` item as we have used `toList()`

i know i am late to give answer on this :)

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` will "stack" calls. It will subscribe to each of Observable then emit results in order of their arrival. So results may **not** be ordered (cf [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)).

If you wants that results are ordered, you should look at the `concatMap` operator.(see [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMap(rx.functions.Func1)))

```
Observable.from(myList)
     .concatMap{ item ->
              return serviceInteractor.uploadToServer(item)
      }
     .map { serverResponse ->
         return serverResponse.getResponseCode
      }
     .toList()
     .subscrible{ responseList ->
         // do something with all the responses
     }
```

You can get more information throught [this blog post.](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/)