# How do I reference a variable through multiple sequential, dependent AsyncTasks in Java for Android?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, async-await

I need to submit a sequence of API calls where the response of the first call contains the API address needed for the second call. I then want to send the results of the second call back into MainActivity. Additionally, each response is updated over time as results of those calls are returned.

I have set up my code to use a sequence of AsyncTasks with success and fail criteria to keep them active. Despite researching practically every article I can on this, none of them seem to show how to reference and parse a returned variable from the execute() method in the code instead of directly updating the GUI. I also need to do all of this without leaking memory or blocking the main threads.

```
class CheckItemStatus extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final String itemName;
    String mResponse = "";
    String submitReportURL = "stackoverflow.com";

    public CheckItemStatus(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        new RetrieveFeedTask(submitReportURL).execute();

        return mResponse;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);

        String reportURLResponse = "";

        // TODO: Retrieve new response
        Log.i("APP", "Item check submitted! Response: " + reportURLResponse);

        String reportURL = ""; // TODO: Parse new response for report URL
        new CheckReportResults(itemName, reportURL).execute();
    }
}

class CheckReportResults extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final String itemName;
    private final String reportURL;
    String mResponse = "";

    public CheckReportResults(String itemName, String reportURL) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.reportURL = reportURL;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        Log.i("APP", "Waiting for results for item " + itemName);

        new RetrieveFeedTask(reportURL).execute();

        return mResponse;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
    }
}

class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String URL;


    public RetrieveFeedTask(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        String response="{\n" +
                "    \"reportURL\": \"stackoverflow.com\"\n" +
                "}";

        // Open Connection and Get Response
        return response;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);

        if (response == null) {
            response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
        }

        Log.i("INFO", "Response: " + response);

    }
}
```

Currently, the code runs, but I have no idea how to parse and reference those responses outside of the AsyncTask class.

Comment: Why can't you try using RxJava ??

Comment: I haven't heard of it! Any chance you could provide an example of how I would approach this using RxJava?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264933/rxjava-sequential-execution?rq=1 Refer this link also, look at RxJava sequential call examples. Hope this will help

Comment: Thank you! I can look into refactoring this in the future using RxJava, but since the code is working and there are no examples of how to do this on the site, I would still love to get an answer on how to have the result return and get parsed correctly with the current code... Unless a refactor is the only way to make it viable!